# php fail to print an array of object

Tags: php

My php code is:

```
<?php
    class Product {
        var $product_name;
        var $retailer;

        function __constructor($product, $retailer) {
            $this->product_name = $product;
            $this->retailer = $retailer;
        }

        function getProduct() {
            return $this->product_name;
        }
    }

    $product_arr = array();

    for ($f = 0; $f < 100; $f++) {
        array_push($product_arr, new Product("asd", "xcxcxc"));
    }
    print_r($product_arr);
?>
```

The code is pretty simple, I have a class called "Product", I build an array consists of 100 Product object, but when I tried to print the array, I found out all the object's product_name and retailer fields are empty. Not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong name:

```
    function __constructor($product, $retailer) {
                       ^^^
```

PHP's standard constructor name is simply `__construct` (no `or`). So you never actually called a constructor, which means your variable assignments never executed.

Comment: correct and fast and why not  the numbers show the knowledge. +10